# Laravel 5 - insert multiple users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a simple User - Department relationship.  My User Model has the following

```
public function department() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department', 'departmentId');
}
```

And my Department Model has

```
public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

At the moment I am working with the departments side of things.  My index function looks like the following

```
public function index() {
    $departments = Helper::returnDepartmentsFromLdap();

    return view('departments.index', compact('departments'));
}
```

What it basically does it gets all the departments from LDap (Active Directory) and displays them.  On the index page for departments, I have

```
{!! link_to_route('departments.updateDepartments', 'Update Database', null, array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
```

So the database can be updated if new departments are added to our server.  I do not have a create function as it is not needed.

Anyways, at the moment, my routes are like so

```
Route::model('departments', 'Department');
Route::bind('departments', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Department::whereId($value)->first();
});
Route::resource('departments', 'DepartmentsController', ['except' => ['show', 'edit', 'create', 'delete', 'update', 'destroy']]);
Route::post('departments/updateDepartments', array('as' => 'departments.updateDepartments', 'uses' => 'DepartmentsController@updateDepartments'));
```

And in my updateDepartments function I am simply doing the following for now

```
public function updateDepartments()
{
   dd("TEST");
}
```

If I click on the button on my index page to update the database, which should trigger the above, I am seeing a MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use get:
because you can only pass data using get method with link link_to_route

```
Route::get('departments/updateDepartments', array('as' => 'departments.updateDepartments', 'uses' => 'DepartmentsController@updateDepartments'));
```

Comment: Will get allow me to still add data to the database?  I am not using a form because data is obtained from LDAP, so within the updateDepartments function, I will get all departments from LDAP, and then save/update them in database

Answer (score 1):

`Route::post('departments/updateDepartments', ...)` means you only allow POST requests on that route. Make sure the form method is POST instead of GET (default) on your index page

Comment: The problem is that I am not using a form, because the departments are obtained from LDAP, therefore I never need to enter information about a department